# Rails form to upload a file to directory - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, controller

I'm trying to create a form that uploads a pdf and an image to a directory. I currently have this code, which i've copied off a working example:

```
def resources_addprocess

  r = Resource.new
  r.title = params[:title]
  r.reference = params[:reference]
  r.description = params[:description]
  r.campaign = params[:campaign]
  r.resourcetype = params[:resourcetype]

  uploaded_io = params[:file]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public','resources', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
  if params[:preview].present?
    uploaded_io2 = params[:preview]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('app','assets','images','preview', 'resources', uploaded_io2.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io2.read)
    end
    r.preview = uploaded_io2.original_filename
  end
  r.file = uploaded_io.original_filename

  if r.save
    flash[:success] = "You successfully added a resource."
    redirect_to "/cms/resources"
  else
    flash[:error] = "resource wasn't successfully."
    redirect_to "/cms/resources"
  end
end
```

But I get the following error: `undefined method 'original_filename'` This worked on a different project.. not sure why it isn't now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer just after posting this,

Turns out if you use the `=form_tag` you need to define it's multipart..

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files